# solution of a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis

I have the differential equation $y'=t^2+e^{-y(t)^2}+1$ with $y(0)=-1$

I have to prove that the solution $y(t)$ is null in $t_0 \in R$ and $t_0\in (0,1)$

$y'>0$ so the solution is monotonically increasing on $R$

Answer (score 2):

We have the differential inequality

$$y' \geq t^2+1 ,$$

and integrating both sides from $0$ to $t$ gives

$$y(t)-y(0) \geq \frac{t^3}{3}+t, $$

so

$$y(t) \geq \frac{t^3}{3}+t-1.$$

As the function $\frac{t^3}{3}+t-1$ evaluates to $\frac{1}{3}$ when $t=1$, there must exist a $t_0 \in (0,1)$ as the question expects.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the $+1$ on the right hand side.